# Managing timezones when concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

My code below uses a couple of function calls to first get historical data for a stock, save it into a dataframe, then get live data every 5 sec and append it to the dataframe. It is working well, except that handling the timezones is getting tricky.

Notice in the output that the timezome and format of the date in the first 4 rows is different from the last row. Any idea how to fix this? tz_localize() and tz_convert() don't appear to be helping much.

```
def onBarUpdate(bars, hasNewBar):
    df_new_bar = pd.DataFrame([[bars[-1].time, bars[-1].open_, bars[-1].high, bars[-1].low, bars[-1].close, bars[-1].count]], columns=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
    df_new_bar.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df_new_bar.tz_convert('Pacific/Johnston')
    df_5_sec = pd.concat([df_5_sec, df_new_bar], axis='rows')
    print(df_5_sec.tail(5))
 
def main():
    bars_hist = ib.reqHistoricalData(
        contract,
        endDateTime='',
        durationStr='2500 S',
        barSizeSetting='5 secs',
        whatToShow='TRADES',
        useRTH=True,
        keepUpToDate=False,
        formatDate=1)
    df_5_sec = pd.DataFrame(bars_hist)
    df_5_sec.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df_5_sec.tz_localize('Pacific/Johnston')

    bars = ib.reqRealTimeBars(contract, 5, 'TRADES', False)
    ib.barUpdateEvent += onBarUpdate
```

```
date                       open  high   low  close  volume
2022-06-13 12:59:40        4.290   4.3  4.29  4.295     257
2022-06-13 12:59:45        4.300   4.3  4.29  4.295     183
2022-06-13 12:59:50        4.295   4.3  4.29  4.300     139
2022-06-13 12:59:55        4.300   4.3  4.29  4.295      57
2022-06-13 20:12:55+00:00  4.300   4.3  4.30  4.300       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution for other's benefit. In the definition for function onBarUpdate, replacing bars[-1].time with the following did the trick. It converts the time to US/Pacific and strips out the timezone.

```
pd.to_datetime(bars[-1].time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```